# Dynamic Import com Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Em uma aplicação *VueJS* com template *Webpack*, tenho a necessidade de importar uma série de *SVG's* de acordo com os parâmetros de um usuário.

Os *SVG's* são arquivos fixos, mas são carregados dinamicamente na aplicação. Se eu importar todos os arquivos de uma vez, o `bundle` fica muito grande (por volta de 13mb). Também não consegui utilizar o `dynamic import` porque neste caso o `import` seria uma expressão, algo como `import(x)` onde x é o nome do arquivo a ser importado de acordo com os parâmetros do usuário.

Qual seria a solução para este problema? Como posso realizar o *lazy load* de um *asset* de acordo com os parâmetros do usuário?

Comment: Podes servir esse conteúdo por ajax?

Comment: É uma solução caso não seja possível realizar esse import

Comment: @Sergio, um problema que vejo com ajax é ter de controlar o cache desse arquivo uma vez carregado... algo que o dynamic import faz com maior facilidade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível realizar o `import` dos arquivos `inline` através do `svg-inline-loader` no `Webpack`. Para evitar a colisão dos `imports svg` nos arquivos `CSS` foi necessário utilizar a configuração `issuer`. O `webpack.base.config` ficou assim:

```
{
  test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
  issuer: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 10000,
    name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
  }
},
{
  test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
}
```

Para realização dinâmica do `import` o seguinte trecho de código pode ser utilizado

```
let fileName = 'foo.svg'

import(`./svg/${fileName}.svg`)
      .then(module => { ... } )
```